# Inheritance from native objects

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I seem to miss something about the constructor chain inheritance in Javascript, with native objects. For example :

```
function ErrorChild(message) { Error.call(this, message); }
ErrorChild.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
var myerror = new ErrorChild("Help!");
```

Why `myerror.message` is defined as `""` after those statements ? I would expect the Error constructor to define it as "Help!" (and override the default value of `Error.prototype.message`), like if I was doing :

```
var myerror = new Error("Help!")
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple work-around: [**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/Px8PV/)

```
function ErrorChild(name, message) {
    // Error.call(this); this is not needed
    this.name = name;
    this.message = message;
}

ErrorChild.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
ErrorChild.prototype.constructor = ErrorChild;

var myerror = new ErrorChild("test", "Help!");
document.body.innerHTML += myerror.message;
```

The above doesn't break the expected behaviour. When you `throw myerror`, the correct `name` and `message` will display.

**The problem**

From the ECMA5 Language Specification:

> 15.11.1 The Error Constructor Called as a Function
>
> When Error is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it
>   creates and initialises a new Error object. Thus the function call
>   Error(...) is equivalent to the object creation expression new
>   Error(...) with the same arguments.

The problem: `Error.call(this)`, is the equivalent of `new Error`. But the `new Error` instantiation will not set the `name` or `message`. `new Error` will initialise `message` with `""` by default.

> 15.11.4.3 Error.prototype.message # Ⓣ Ⓡ The initial value of Error.prototype.message is the empty String.

**Test**([**proof**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/Px8PV/4/))

If inside your `ErrorChild` you were to add:

```
var test = Error.call(this, message);
console.dir(test);
console.log(test instanceof Error); // true;
console.log(test.message); // "Help!";
```

The `test` reflects the ECMA5 spec. An `Error` instance with a proper `message` set.

Conclusion:

Because `Error.call(arguments);` gets automatically translated to `new Error(arguments);` scope is lost, so the properties are never initialised on the `this` object.

When `Object.create(Error.prototype)` is used, the `message` property takes the default value, the empty String.

Comment: The Problem is that [calling `Error` as a function](http://es5.github.io/#x15.11.1) behaves as calling the constructor (`new Error`)

Comment: Naah i waited if you update your answer to explain the problem,I thought you won't; now I answered it too :D

Comment: Yeah I noticed your edit 10 secs after my Answer^^ (+1 for this) , Indeed quite an Interesting question *(though asked several times already)*
A communinity wiki wold be nice for a question like this (why not dupe this one as cw?).

Yeah, but i think they cover the problem quite good. =)

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question!
Is there any other native objects that display other weird behavior like this? For example, I tried the same code, but replacing Error by String, and it also seems to be problematic (my StringChild instance can't be used as a normal string).

Comment: A few other question that pops up into my mind :
1) I guess I can test this by typing for example String.call(this,any_argument) in a console, and see if something is returned ?
2) Does it only happen with native objects ?
3) Why would you have constructor returning constructed object instead of assigning to this? This breaks the whole prototype chain and only allows you to do "var e = Error(message)" instead of "var e = new Error(message)"
Thanks ! :)

Comment: For correctness' sake, could you remove the `Error.call(this)` in your constructor, as it unneccessary creates an Object, which gets GC'ed when the constructor finished ? =)

Comment: @alex23 even `ErrorChild.prototype = Error.prototype` alone is enough =)

Comment: You don't seem to have understood [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). Please fix your code

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is not the inheritance chain, but rather the fact that [calling `Error` as a function](http://es5.github.io/#x15.11.1) behaves as calling the constructor, instantiating a `new Error` Object

Therefore when calling your `new ErrorChild` the code executed is actually equivalent to

```
function ErrorChild(message) {
 new Error (message) 
}
```

Wait. But this only creates a new Error Object which is **not** used anywhere *(and also not returned by your constructor)*. And simply gets forgotten about.

So this actually **doesn't** modify your actual `ErrorChild` instance.

Therefore the `message` propertie you are accessing is the one shadowed by `ErrorChild.prototype` which inherits from `Error.protyotype` and therefore contains the `message`'s **default** value an Empty String `""`

But you can "mimic" an Error Object simply.

As you only need the [`toString` method's defined behaviour](http://es5.github.io/#x15.11.4.4) and 2 properties

- `name`
- `message`

To cover the Error's standard properties.

You can simply set your constructors prototype to `Error.prototype`
And assign `name` and `message` manually.

```
function ErrorChild (name,message) {
  this.name = name;
  this.message = message;
}
ErrorChild.prototype = Error.prototype;
```

Now you can simply create a `new ErrorChild (...)` instance.

Which you can `throw` around `log` and `catch` ->

`throw new ErrorChild("CustomError","Help") //Uncaught CustomError: Help`

Heres a [JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/azediw/1/edit)